# Append line numbers at end of each line in the file

Tags: text-processing

In a peculiar case I needed some of my text files to append with line number at the end. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `awk` program stores the current line in variable `$0` and the record number ("line number") in `NR`. This command will print the lines with a line number appended:

```
awk '{ print $0, NR }' yourfile.txt
```

For prepending line numbers, there also exist the [`nl`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#nl-invocation) command ("number lines of files"):

```
nl yourfile.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

There will be a million ways to do this. Here's another one:

```
sed -n 'p;=' file | paste -d":" - -
```

paste's default delimiter is tab, if you omit the -d option